# Is there any way in AWS to tun off instance if bill increases certain amount

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I know there is a option if `CPU increases` certain load then `Ec2` instance can be terminated.

But i want to free my mind that if due to any reason my bill increases some amount say 100$ then my Ec2 instance should turned off.

If happend with me, i was lucky to get email but i checked email after 15 hrs and i got 200$ bill due to some ddos attack on server.

Comment: Contact amazon support on how to do this

Comment: You can set up alerts to warn you if your AWS bill exceeds specific amounts. Amazon published this to describe how to do it in the console: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html I published the following with command line instructions: http://alestic.com/2013/01/aws-billing-alerts You could have the alert be sent to the instance triggering a shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Create a Billing Alarm to Notify You If Your Usage Exceeds the Free Tier](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/awsgsg-intro/gsg-aws-billing-alert.html)